# How to give push permissions on branches to specific people on git?

Tags: github

I have been going through git branch and its protection rules but I am not able to identify there how to restrict specific people and give access to specific people for push on specific branches. It has options related to branch only and nothing about which user can do a push or not. Is there any way we can associate branches with specific people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [branch restrictions](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-branch-restrictions) when using GitHub Team, GitHub Enterprise Cloud, or GitHub Enterprise Server. There does not seem to be a way to do it with other plans.

When [enabled](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-branch-restrictions), you can set it so that only certain users have push access to each protected branch, configured separately.